# How would I add an array of strings into a binary tree without hitting max iterations in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I have a dictionary of words containing 370100 elements (strings). I need to add them into a binary tree to sort and find them. How would I do this without hitting python's max iterations? I tried using sys.setrecursionlimit but it was slow and eventually spit out zsh: segmentation fault python tree.py.

```
import sys

class Node(object):

def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.count = 1

def __str__(self):
    return 'value: {0}, count: {1}'.format(self.value, self.count)

def insert(root, value):
if not root:
    return Node(value)
elif root.value == value:
    root.count += 1
elif value < root.value:
    root.left = insert(root.left, value)
else:
    root.right = insert(root.right, value)

return root

def create(seq):
root = None
for word in seq:
    root = insert(root, word)

return root

def search(root, word, depth=1):
if not root:
    return 0, 0
elif root.value == word:
    return depth, root.count
elif word < root.value:
    return search(root.left, word, depth + 1)
else:
    return search(root.right, word, depth + 1)

def print_tree(root):
if root:
    print_tree(root.left)
    print (root)
    print_tree(root.right)

def toArr(txtfile):
txtArr = []
file = txtfile
for line in file:
    txtArr.append(line)
return txtArr



dictionary = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
dic = toArr(dictionary)
sys.setrecursionlimit(370100)

tree = create(dic)

print_tree(tree)
```

This is what I have. Any solutions would be appreciated! :)

Comment: binary tree of 370k elements should have 19 depth (log2(370k)) recursion which is small. You probably have bug in your implementation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to posit there's nothing (at least, not much) wrong with your code, but rather your data is at fault.  If your input is ***sorted***, you will end up with stack overflow -- this approach assumes randomly scattered data.  Otherwise, you end up with a lopsided tree and a stack overflow.  With my own test list of 250K words, I was able to get your code to work if I shuffled them, and get your code to break if I sorted them.

My rework of your code to turn some of your functions into methods:

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.count = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return 'value: {0}, count: {1}'.format(self.value, self.count)

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.print_tree()

        print(self)

        if self.right:
            self.right.print_tree()

    def search(self, word, depth=1):
        if self.value == word:
            return depth, self.count

        if word < self.value:
            if self.left:
                return self.left.search(word, depth + 1)
        else:
            if self.right:
                return self.right.search(word, depth + 1)

        return 0, 0

def insert(root, value):
    if not root:
        return Node(value)

    if root.value == value:
        root.count += 1
    elif value < root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, value)
    else:
        root.right = insert(root.right, value)

    return root

def create(seq):
    root = None

    for word in seq:
        root = insert(root, word)

    return root

def toArr(txtfile):
    with open(txtfile) as file:
        return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]

array = toArr('dictionary.txt')

tree = create(array)

tree.print_tree()
```